# Definindo valores 'default' para variávei com o Template Engine Pug

Tags: html, node.js, express.js, jade, pug

Estou começando a trabalhar com o MEAN e utilizo como template engine o [Pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug). Sei que o mesmo era o Jade anteriormente e que houveram atualizações na forma de trabalhar com o mesmo.

Meu problema é que, em Jade, e em diversos locais na internet, eu tenho a informação que para definir um valor 'default' para uma variável que seja passada, eu posso usar uma declaração como essa:

**Pedaço do código da aplicação com o parametro a ser passado**

```
// ...
app.get('/',function(req, res){
    res.render('foo', {
        'bar':'hello ',
        //'bin': 'world!!!' // <-- variavel comentada de proprósito
    });
})
```

**Meu arquivo foo.pug**

```
html
  head
    title= Testando
  body
    bar bin
```

O problema em questão é que, se `bin` não é enviado, meu *foo.pug* da pau na renderização dizendo que não encontrou a variável. Como eu defino um valor 'default' caso `bin` não seja enviado no meu template?

Comment: Não percebi bem qual é a sintaxe para valores default... dizes que é o proprio código comentado `//'bin': 'world!!!'`? Podes fazer merge de objetos e o objeto inicial ter o valor defenido, que será sobrescrito caso haja outro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei algumas soluções que dependem da forma de desenvolvimento em que está sendo aplicada:

**Solução 1:** Utilizando um condicionador `if else` para checar se existe ou não o elemento:

```
html
  head
    title= Testando
body
  if (bar && bin)
    bar bin
  else if (bar && !bin)
    bar world!!!
```

*Essa solução é interessante quando se têm a importação de um arquivo ou um bloco de código misto entre variáveis e conteúdo*.

**Solução 2:** Utilizando operadores tenários para validação do campo:

```
html
  head
    title= Testando
body
  typeof bin == 'undefined' ? bar world!!! : bar bin
```

*Trabalhando com operadores tenários, você sempre terá um callback para aquele parâmetro*.

**Solução 3:** declarar essas variáveis com o recurso *[Unbuffered Code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unbuffered-code)*:

```
- var bin = bin || 'world!!!';
- var bar = bar || 'hello ';
html
  head
    title= Testando
body
    bar bin
```

*Percebi que assim posso alterar o valor das variáveis dependendo do arquivo a ser importado, ou seja, se houver uma nova declaração* `- var bin = bin || 'foo!!!';` *consigo alterar o valor default do conteúdo que deveria ser mostrado ou da expressão que bin será declarada como em * `- var bin = '123'`.

**Solução 4:** declarar essas variáveis com o recurso *[Buffered Code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#buffered-code)*:

```
html
  head
    title= Testando
body= (bar || 'hello ') + (bin || 'world!!!')
```

*Essa solução é uma implementação da Solução 2 sem a declaração das variantes. O Pug entende que o conteúdo do tipo document.body.innerHTML (que é a tag em questão) será completado com o resultado da expressão.*

**Solução 5:** declarar essas variáveis com o recurso *[Unescaped Buffered Code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unescaped-buffered-code)*:

```
html
  head
    title= Testando
body
  != (bar || 'hello ') + (bin || 'world!!!')
```

*Essa solução, que para mim vejo como mais satisfatória, permite que em qualquer lugar, independente se estou dentro de um bloco de conteúdo, eu possa inserir uma expressão completa, assim não dependo de uma tag*.